# CSS Cross-browser opacity from Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, browser, cross-browser

I want to turn down the opacity on an element when a user performs an action.

The current code I have is:

```
document.getElementById('MyOpaqueElement').style.opacity = 0.3;
// There are checks in the real code for NULL, etc.
```

This works on Firefox, Safari, etc.  IE8 has different ideas about opacity. I have read a couple of articles but have yet to find a definitive answer on the most portable method to do this in a cross-browser way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various browsers-specific settings and notations you need to take into consideration.

See [**Quirksmode.org: CSS2 - Opacity**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)

I suggest using a Framework like [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [MooTools](http://www.mootools.net) or [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/). I know it seems ridiculous to add dozens of kilobytes of code just for some opacity at first, but it's really worth it. It just works in *one* way for all browsers.

Comment: I am already using JQuery (obviously not enough). I don't see a direct opacity feature. Can I add opacity $('XXX').css('opacity',0.3); or should I append another class to the element (Not sure how to do that).

Comment: There's `$(element).fadeTo(0, 0.5);` See http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeTo#speedopacitycallback but there may be something even more elegant around.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT- Poster is using jquery..

Easy way:

```
  $(el).css('opacity', '0.3');
```

(I checked the jquery sources, and it handles opacity for cross-browser compatibility automatically, so that should work)

Or for a CSS solution:
Just give it a class, e.g. 'transparent', and add this to your CSS file:

```
.transparent {
    filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* for IE */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.3;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.3;       /* old mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.3;           /* good browsers: FF, safari, opera */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent should be `document.getElementById('MyOpaqueElement').style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=30)';`

By the way, even if you don't use a library like YUI or JQuery, you can download them and search their sources for the word

> opacity

.